# How to set currency type to a column in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I convert  a  column to  currency  type in  XSSFWorkbook using  poi in java ?

Here is the code I  have used :

```
DataFormat datafrmt = wbAll.createDataFormat();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(datafrmt.getFormat("$#,##0.00"));
```

But after setting the data format I tried opening the Excel sheet and checked the format of the column it shows custom type but I need the column to be a currency  type. How  can I  achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you use one of the [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) for currency. This one seems to be the one you're looking for `7, "$#,##0.00);($#,##0.00)"`.

Check how [Apache suggests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/BigGridDemo.java) doing it by making a `Map` of `XSSFCellStyle` in their demo. After reading it, I think you are only missing this line of code for you format to work.

```
XSSFCellStyle style3 = wb.createCellStyle();
style3.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);  // THIS LINE HERE!
style3.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("$#,##0.00"));
styles.put("currency", style3);`
```

To use the `BuiltinFormats`, instead of using a `XSSFDataFormat` instance, you directly set the short of the wanted format, like this
    `style3.setDataFormat((short) 7);`

Comment: ok,Thanks for the code  ,i had imported the  static class and used the  builtinformat  method but how  do  i  set  it  to  cell style?

Comment: Edited with some clarifications.

Comment: @ClintBrown Found it back, they moved their repo.