# Display dollar amount value in excel using Apache POI without clicking in the cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to display amount value with dollar currency sign in excel (.xlsx) sheet using POI.
what I am setting the actual value is: 2156820.54 and 
what I am expecting to see in excel is: $2,156,820.54

I am doing

```
XSSFCellStyle curStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
XSSFDataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
curStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("$#,#0.00"));
cell.setCellStyle(curStyle);
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue("2156820.54");
```

When I am generating excel sheet and opening it in MS Office excel then cell value displays 2156820.54 only. But when I double click in the cell and hit Enter or simply leave the cell after double click, cell value gets changed to $2,156,820.54. But I want this formatted value to be displayed when I open the excel sheet and should not be needed to click in the cell to get the formatting done.

I have also tried curStyle.setDataFormat((short)7); but same result with it too. Is it issue with my way of formatting or something related to MS excel itself?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186898/how-to-set-currency-type-to-a-column-in-poi

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried it but only additional thing it did is just an alignment. I still need to double click within the cell to see amount value formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting the value as a string. Formatting rules in Excel only apply to numbers, they do not apply to strings

(Try it in Excel - format two cells as %, enter `1.5` in one, `'1.5` in the other, and see that only the number version gets formatted)

This line here:

```
cell.setCellValue("2156820.54");
```

Sets the value as a string, since you're parsing in a string

Instead, change it to

```
cell.setCellValue(2156820.54);
```

And the formatting rules of the cell will then apply, as you're setting it as a number

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr . Setting string value was an issue. By setting numeric value to cell formatting is happening now.